# How to pass a parameter to ajax sucsses function

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I have a php function that get some xml information to be handled, but my problem is to pass a parameter to the function in addition to the data returned from the ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data:{country:'home'},
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data)
    {
       alert(data);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

I want to pass parameter with the data .
I know that I could do it like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data:{country:'home'},
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function do_it(parameter)
});
function do_it(parameter)
{
   return function(data)
  {
    alert(parameter);
    alert(data);
  }
}
```

I do not want to use this way I want to pass the parameter as the first code is showing. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parameter is not affected by the AJAX call, simply define it in the same scope as the call and then access it from the success function.  For example:

```
var parameter = 'some value';
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data: {country: 'home'},
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(parameter);
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

This works because `parameter` is in an outer scope and thus accessible by the success function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `context` option to `$.ajax`. This will then be available as `this` in the callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data:{country:'home'},
    dataType: "xml",
    context: parameter,
    success: function(data)
    {
       alert(data);
       alert(this);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```